# Why does vim not apply these color variables in my config?

Tags: vim, environment-variables

I have these settings in my vim config, which gets environment variables and uses them to set colors for ale linting errors:

```
" ==================================================================================================
" Theme settings
" ==================================================================================================

let vim_theme=$VIM_THEME
let vim_ale_error_fg=$VIM_ALE_ERROR_FG
let vim_ale_error_bg=$VIM_ALE_ERROR_BG
let vim_ale_warning_fg=$VIM_ALE_WARNING_FG
let vim_ale_warning_bg=$VIM_ALE_WARNING_BG

if vim_theme == 'gruvbox'
  if has_key(g:plugs, 'gruvbox')
    colorscheme gruvbox
    let g:gruvbox_italic = 1
  endif

  if has_key(g:plugs, 'vim-airline')
    let g:airline_theme='gruvbox'
  endif

  if has_key(g:plugs, 'ale')
    highlight ALEErrorSign guifg=vim_ale_error_fg guibg=vim_ale_error_bg
    highlight ALEWarningSign guifg=vim_ale_warning_fg guibg=vim_ale_warning_bg
  endif
endif
```

I've checked, and the variables are available:

```bash
echo $VIM_ALE_ERROR_FG
#fb4934
```

So why are they not applied? The `if vim_theme == 'gruvbox'` line works fine, but setting the colors doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it. Highlight doesn't accept variables as arguments, so you need to use `:exe` to bypass that. So this does work:

```
if has_key(g:plugs, 'ale')
  exe 'highlight ALEErrorSign guifg=' . vim_ale_error_fg 'guibg=' . vim_ale_error_bg
  exe 'highlight ALEWarningSign guifg=' . vim_ale_warning_fg 'guibg=' . vim_ale_warning_bg
endif
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2211738/5918874